# Mongoid Object.all seems to return a lot of []

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

Why doesn't this work:

```
ruby-1.8.7-p249 > List.create :search_terms => 'foo'
 => #<List _id: 4c9044a02249c7a5e2000001, search_terms: "foo", user_id: nil> 

ruby-1.8.7-p249 > List.all
 => #<Mongoid::Criteria:0x1030dea90 @klass=List, @documents=[], @selector={}, @options={}> 

ruby-1.8.7-p249 > List.all.documents
 => []
```

Comment: But this works: 

    ruby-1.8.7-p249 > List.all.map{|l|l}
    [#<List _id: 4c9043d02249c7a502000003, search_terms: "test", user_id: 1>, #<List _id: 4c9044a02249c7a5e2000001, search_terms: "foo", user_id: nil>, #<List _id: 4c90f9b92249c7a5e2000002, search_terms: "foo", user_id: nil, user: 1>]

Comment: I guess this has something to do with the way they do lazy loading. This means that records are fetched when they are accessed (for example through #map, #each or #[]).
Perhaps try `x = List.all; x.first; x.documents` to see if that's the problem?

Answer (score 17):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
List.all.to_a
```

Comment: @cleamensp - I up-voted your answer. but you didn't explained solution in detail. Please describe answer too it will very helpful.